# Template keywords can't handle line break in RF 3.2.1

Tags: robotframework

This test case if working fine in Robot Framework 3.1.2 but in 3.2.1 I'm getting error message:

> Setting 'Template' accepts only one value, got 2.

I can't see that there is any updates to the documentation that explains this. Any ideas?

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    [Template]    The result of ${calculation}
    ...           should be ${expected}
    1 + 1    2
    2 + 2    4

*** Keywords ***
The result of ${calculation} should be ${expected}
    ${result} =    Evaluate    ${calculation}
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${result}     ${expected}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `...` marks an argument boundary. What you did is exactly the same as this:

```
[Template]    The result of ${calculation}    should be ${expected}
```

Like the error says, the `[Template]` setting only accepts a single argument but you're passing two. You cannot define the keyword on multiple lines.

It appears that the old (pre 3.2) parser may have been a bit lax and allowed you to split the template keyword on multiple lines. The new parser doesn't allow that.

Comment: That's to bad. This is of course a simplification of my problem. My keyword will be much harder to understand if I have to keep it under 120 characters (which is the max line length in the project).